# Opening Unity project developed on Windows results in compilation errors on Linux?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-22.04

I was getting the following error upon the project launch on Ubuntu-22.04:

> Unity Package Manager Error
> An error occurred while resolving packages:
> One or more packages could not be added to the local file system: com.unity.ide.visualstudio: [/home/a_a/.config/unity3d/cache/npm/ packages.unity.com/com.unity.ide.visualstudio/2.0.22/package.tgz] is not a valid package tarball.

And the following errors in the log/console upon opening it in Safe Mode:

> Library/PackageCache/com.unity.2d.spriteshape@9.0.2/Runtime/SpriteShapeGenerator.cs(36,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BurstCompileAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

> Win32Exception: Access denied
> System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) (at <5fe808a9ce234d7cb9b1a4e14f988a80>:0)
> System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () (at <5fe808a9ce234d7cb9b1a4e14f988a80>:0)
> (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
> UnityEditor.DefaultExternalCodeEditor.OpenProject (System.String path, System.Int32 line, System.Int32 column) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/CodeEditor/DefaultExternalCodeEditor.cs:177)
> Unity.CodeEditor.CodeEditor.OpenProject (System.String path, System.Int32 line, System.Int32 column) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/CodeEditor/CodeEditor.cs:73)
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:190)

> The .meta file Packages/com.unity.burst/ValidationConfig.json.meta does not have a valid GUID and its corresponding Asset file will be ignored. If this file is not malformed, please add a GUID, or delete the .meta file and it will be recreated correctly

I've tried:

1. reinstalling UnityHub and Editor, the version of the Editor matches the one the project was developed in
2. removing lines mentioning unity.ide.visualstudio from both .json files in the project's Packages folder
3. setting Unity Editor > Edit > Preferences > External Tools > External Script Editor: Visual Studio Code in the opened in Safe Mode project
4. Edit > Project Settings > Editor > End of Line Sequences: Unix
5. forcing Unity to re-import all assets and regenerate the Library folder in the project by deleting the Library folder
6. removing com.unity.ide.visualstudio from .config/unity3d/cache/npm/packages.unity.com project folder

Now the Editor.log file starts with

> Unity Editor version:    2022.3.11f1 (d00248457e15)
> Branch:                  2022.3/staging
> Build type:              Release
> Batch mode:              NO
> System name:             Linux
> Distro version:          #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct  6 10:23:26 UTC 2
> Kernel version:          6.2.0-35-generic
> Architecture:            x86_64
> Available memory:        7626 MB

and upon the Compiling Scripts step of the launch I get the "The project you're opening contains compilation errors." error message.

Screenshot depicting all of the project's packages:
[image: Screenshot depicting all of the project's packages]

Comment: in safe mode, id have removed the vs package if it was in use, and/or added burst.. Id also have gone to the cache folder and removed the tgz it says isnt valid.

Comment: @BugFinder there seems to be no VS package and burst is present (and cannot be removed for reinstallation), rm'ing the offensive tgz was done in step 5

Comment: well in step 1 you said you removed it from the json, so, it had been there..  Id have done it through unity, however, in one part its talking home/a_a and in another /home/bokken  as a unix admin, im not surprised it says access denied

Comment: @BugFinder, thx for pointing out, the search results have indicated it being a common build problem on Linux. but it's not a folder with the PC username